# Controlling amount of Scroll in Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have a Horizontal scroll view in my app which consists of 9 images. It has to display a set of 3 images at a time. I mean one scroll has to display a set of 3 images.

Now with the default behavior when i scroll fast from right to left its getting to the final set of images. Is there any method to control the amount of scroll and achieve my requirement. Any sample code will be of great help

Comment: What do you mean by "one scroll". Do you mean one swipe of the finger? You could add arrows to the left and right of your HorizontalScroll that would pan the scrollview by the amount of 3 image widths...